# Undesired worksheet cell selection after double clicking vba form list box item

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a form where a user has to populate a statement with finance account codes. Double-click on a cell to launch a form, search for the appropriate account code and double-click on the account code to populate the active cell with it.

The form functionality works well but there is also an undesired effect where cells behind the form item are also selected as the form is unloaded. Instead, there should be no change to the active cell.

Would anyone know how to avoid this selection?

This is what the form looks like:

[image]

And the code that populates the double clicked list box item:

```
Private Sub lbox_gl_account_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Call addGlAccountToCell
    'Hide the form after adding the account
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub addGlAccountToCell()
    Dim selectedIndex As Long 'Index of the selected account within the form
    
    selectedIndex = Me.lbox_gl_account.ListIndex
    
    'If at least any account is selected populate its value. Otherwise its index is -1 and do nothing
    If selectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Error: No account appears to has been selected. No changes made."
     Else
        ActiveCell.Value2 = Me.lbox_gl_account.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The form launches when double clicking in any cell within range S10:S999 of sheet statement. Event handler code below which launches the form is included in ThisWorkbook Excel object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S10:S9999")) Is Nothing Then  
        Dim cell As Range
      
        'Capture the clicked cell in a range object
        Set cell = Target
          
        'Center and show the searchbox form
        With frm_search_gl_account
            .StartUpPosition = 0
            .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
            .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
            .Show
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Please do not include macro-enabled file links to your google drive in your question.

Comment: Please include the event handler which launches the form.

Comment: If you want to avoid the cell selection on double-click, then set `Cancel = True` inside `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick`

Comment: Oh wow, I thought I had tried that and it did not work but Cancel = True does work in fact. Thank you